# NotShowing Data-Bound Image (Reporting Services)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I Create an SendWorkOrder.rdl Report for SSRS. In the dataSet I have a field with Image dataType(Value in that database column eg- 0x89504E470D0A1A0A000000....). 
Followed [msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156342(v=sql.100).aspx) article to create data bound image.
I Tried following expressions, But Image Not Showing

```
=First(Fields!Signature.Value, "CasingList")
=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Mid(System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!Signature.Value),105))
=Convert.FromBase64String(First(Fields!Signature.Value, "CasingList"))
```

Comment: try `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Mid(System. Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Fields!Signature.Value),8))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create an image in your report from the database?

I assume you have set up an image control as follows

[image]

Then set the field to be a reference to your 0x89504E470D0A1A0A000000... data

```
=Fields!Marker.Value
```

And the Mime type to the the corresponding image format

```
=Fields!Marker_Type.Value
```

(note this should be something like `image/jpeg` or `image/png`)

Without the image format nothing will render.

A set up such as the above should render correctly, as shown

[image] --> becomes --> [image]