# How to add two or many different images to rdlc report using Dataset?

Tags: c#, rdlc

**When I try to do it I get error like this**
[image]

Comment: so do you want to use database field or external source for image? also you need to show how you have set this image in your report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a data bound (From Database field) Image you should follow this [steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd239367.aspx).

To Add an External Image you should follow this [steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220527.aspx)

Or to Embed an Image in a Report you should follow this [steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd239319.aspx).

**Note:** *I have provided links as I don't know how you want to bind this image in your report.*

[Reference for Dataset field Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526680/notshowing-data-bound-image-reporting-services)

Hope this will help you. Thanks.